# If $X$ is Poisson, find the expectation of $\frac{1}{a+X}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

> If $X$ is a Poisson random variable with $\Pr(X=k)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ and $a>0$ then find the expectation of $\frac{1}{a+X}$

If I make use of $\displaystyle\frac1{a+x}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(a+x)t}dt$

then I obtain;

$\displaystyle\mathbf E\bigg(\frac1{a+X}\bigg)=\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(a+x)t}dt\bigg)e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$

now I can interchange sum and integral, but I don't see how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

The result that I am obtaining using Maple is

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}^{k}}{
 \left( a+k \right) k!}}={\frac {\Gamma  \left( a+1 \right) -a\Gamma 
 \left( a,-\lambda \right) }{{{\rm e}^{\lambda}}a \left( -\lambda
 \right) ^{a}}}
$$

or

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}^{k}}{
 \left( a+k \right) k!}}={\frac {{_{1}F_1(a;\,a+1;\,\lambda)}}{{{\rm e}^{
\lambda}}{a}}}
$$

or

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}^{k}}{
 \left( a+k \right) k!}}={\frac {
{{\rm M}\left(a,\,a+1,\,\lambda\right)}}{{{\rm e}^{\lambda}}{a}}}
$$

Other related results are:

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}^{k}}{
 \left( a+k \right) ^{2}k!}}={\frac {{_2F_2(a,a;\,a+1,a+1;\,\lambda)}}{
{{\rm e}^{\lambda}}{a}^{2}}}
$$

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}^{k}}{
 \left( a+k \right) ^{3}k!}}={\frac {
{_3F_3(a,a,a;\,a+1,a+1,a+1;\,\lambda)}}{{{\rm e}^{\lambda}}{a}^{3}}}
$$

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}^{k}}{
 \left( a+k \right) ^{n}k!}}={\frac {
{_nF_n(a,..,a;\,a+1,..,a+1;\,\lambda)}}{{{\rm e}^{\lambda}}{a}^{n
}}}
$$